# Is there any mathematical term for $<x^2>$?

Tags: statistics, terminology, expected-value

$<x>$ is known as expectation of *x*. But is there any mathematical term for $<x^2>$; or is it just known as expectation of $x^2$?

Comment: In mathematics the expected value of a random variable $X$ is indicated as $\mathbb{E}[X]$

Comment: Hey my bad, I wrote the question wrong. I was asking for $<x^2>$ not $<x>$...

Comment: The second moment.

Comment: In group theory, $\langle x\rangle$ is the cyclic subgroup generated by $x$.

Comment: Squared variation?

Comment: Consider accepting the answer if it was helpful to you

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments, the expectation of a random variable $X$ is usually denoted by $\mathbb{E}[X]$. Regarding your question, the expression $\mathbb{E}[X^2]$ is known as the *second moment of X*. In general, for a natural number $n$, $\mathbb{E}[X^n]$ is known as the $n$-th moment. There is quite a lot of theory concerning this.

One more thing that may be of interest is that if the expectation of $X$ is $0$, then the second moment is equal to the variance of $X$. This follows immediately from the formula for the variance.